# Работа с простыми числами на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

На хабре откопал древний код, который ищет простые числа вплоть до указанного числа. У меня условие такое: получить в вводе число, указывающее количество чисел в ответе, т.е., если на вводе будет шестерка, то ожидается нечто такое: [0,1,2,3,4,5] . При этом, мне нужно параллельно проходиться по числам от 1 до бесконечности, пока все ячейки не будут заполнены. Бьюсь не первый час над задачкой. Помогите написать рабочий код. Фрагмент, который откопал, ниже. Как я понял, все четные числа, кроме 2, заменяются на нули, на чем и построен алгоритм.

```
def prime_num(n):
    n = input("n=") #Искать до ЭТОГО числа включительно
    a = list(range(n+1))  #Числа от 0 до максимального искомого (n)
    a[1] = 0        #Не брать в расчет 1
    list_ = []        #Создание списка для записи ответов

    i = 2
    while i <= n:     #Пока не дойдем до максимального числа (n):
        if a[i] != 0: #Если число не равно нулю:
            list_.append(a[i])
            for j in range(i, n+1, i):
                a[j] = 0
        i += 1
    return list_
```

После моей попытки подогнать код под себя, я начал получать в ответе все числа подряд после 7 и теперь н могу разобраться в ЭТОМ. Код приведен ниже.
В идеале - прошу объяснить работу алгоритма целиком, таким, какой он есть и каким должен быть. Но будет достаточно и готового решения.

```
def primes(n):
   
    a = list(range(n**2))
    #print(a) # Пофиксить так, чтобы получалось нужное кол-во элементов Изначально - предел отсчета
    a[1] = 0  # Единицу сразу отсекаем, т.к. она делится только на себя и не является простым числом
    list_ = []

    i = 2  # Начне отсчет с двойки
    print(a)
    
    while len(list_) !=n:
       
        if a[i] != 0: #Заменяются все четные числа на нули
            list_.append(a[i])
            
            for j in range(i, n+1, i): 
                #print(f'a[j] {a[j]} , a {a}')
                a[j] = 0
        #print(i, a)
        i += 1
        
            
        
    return(list_)
print(primes(6))
```

Comment: так какой вам нужен результат?

Comment: Что-то вроде [3,5,7,9,11,13,17] при подаче на ввод 6

Comment: Проблема в том, что для работы алгоритма, который я нашел, необходимо знать, до какого числа считать. Лучших вариантов я не нашел. Выходит, какое бы число я не указал на ввод, рано или поздно я не смогу найти простое число

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def primes(n):
    lst = [2]
    i = 2
    while len(lst) < n:
        for j in lst:
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            lst.append(i)
        i += 1
    return lst

print(primes(6))
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы сначала записываете двойку, т.к. в большинстве случаев будет в списке, затем ищете простые числа и записываете их до тех пор, пока длина списка не станет равной n? Внутри же вы перебираете все значения из вывода и проверяете, делится ли они на предыдущие? Таким образом, вы смогли избежать лишних счетчиков и сделали проверку куда проще. Я правильно понял код? За ответ большое спасибо

Comment: И поясните, пожалуйста, следующие строки кода: 
 if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            lst.append(i)

Я не очень понял, как это работает

Comment: @LegendaryHunter, else относится не к if, а к for.

Comment: Понимаю, спасибо еще раз

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, стоит делать так:

1. Берём [распределение простых чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) `p[k] ~ k * ln(k)` и берём несколько с запасом верхнюю границу.
2. Запускаем [решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) для поиска простых.

Альтернативный вариант:

0. Модифицируем решето Эратосфена таким образом, чтобы оно могло работать с произвольным началом.
1. Запускаем решето Эратосфена до некой границы, которая может быть меньше последнего искомого числа.
2. Пока требуемое количество чисел не найдено, перезапускаем решето с левой границей равной последнему проверенному числу.